# Two implementations of polynomial inversion

Tags: sympy

I'm not very math literate but it seems that the algorithm for computing modular multiplicative inverse of polynomial found at [dup_revert](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/polys/densetools.py#L1261) seems a bit similar to [_series_inversion1](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/polys/ring_series.py#L480).

Please, does anyone know what the difference there is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of `rs_series` module is to use polynomial tools for efficient manipulation of power series, so it's not surprising that it employs similar algorithms. One reason it does not simply borrow all the polynomial methods is that `rs_series` module also works with Puiseux series (where exponents are rational numbers that are not necessarily integers). For example:

```
from sympy.polys.domains import QQ
from sympy.polys.rings import ring
from sympy.polys.ring_series import _series_inversion1
R, x = ring('x', QQ)
p = x**(S(2)/3) + 1
_series_inversion1(p, x, 4)
```

returns `-x**(10/3) + x**(8/3) - x**2 + x**(4/3) - x**(2/3) + 1`, as opposed to

```
R.dup_revert(p, 4)
```

resulting in "TypeError: 'Rational' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: Thank you! So if the exponents are integers, or even natural numbers as in the case of polynomials, these two routines are basically the same, correct?

Comment: Mathematically, they do the same thing. The implementation details, what SymPy classes are used for input and output, are probably different.